# in AS3, how do I make vector2D into compile-time constant?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the vector2D property/method/component in a script I'm working on and it shows up blue as though it's a legitimate AS3 component, however, when I test the code I get error #1046.

Is there some sort of "flash.display..." line I can put up top that will allow the program to recognize vector2D? I can't seem to get a straight answer from the flash website, sad to say.

Alternately, are there any good tutorials or links out there concerning the implementation of SAT (Separation of Axis Theorem) collision in AS3?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply googling [as3 separation axis theorem](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=as3%20separation%20axis%20theorem&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) should help. The [Polygonal  blog post](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=225)  looks quite handy (speedwise and has nice references).

By default as3 provides the [Point](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html) and [Vector3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html) classes if it helps. Point is a bit limited, but Vector3D supports of the typical vector operations (like dot and cross product).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such class as far as I know. There is a Point class however, which is a 2d vector

Answer (score 0):

If you work on something with physics you might consider using (at least partially) Box2d

Answer (score 0):

[Play Chilla](http://www.playchilla.com/vector-2d-for-as3) has a nice implementation for 2D vectors and [Grant Skinner's one](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/01/source_code_see.html) is also quite good.

For tutorials on the SAT algorithm, have a look at the [flash game N's implementation](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique.html) or [this more static tutorial](http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/).